# How to force Orientation as Portrait in iOS 6

Tags: ios, orientation

I am using a  UITabBarController with 4 UINavigationControllers .

In the forth ViewController ,  I wants to restrict its orientation to Portrait only ,
I am using following method but those are not working for me ,
Please help me.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call your ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am Using customized UITabBarController as follows...

### CustomTabBarController.m

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

And

### In ViewControllerToBePorted.m

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return NO;

}
```

Thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0):

From Developer site

"When a view controller is presented over the root view controller, the system behavior changes in two ways. First, the presented view controller is used instead of the root view controller when determining whether an orientation is supported. Second, the presented view controller can also provide a preferred orientation. If the view controller is presented full screen, the user interface is presented in the preferred orientation. The user is expected to see that the orientation is different from the device orientation and rotate the device. A preferred orientation is most often used when the content must be presented in the new orientation."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the orientation of a child view if the parent view has that orientation allowed.

Just imagine this example, you have your tab bar in landscape, and you press the view that is restricted to portrait, what would it happen?

As I said, the orientation of the children has to be orientation of the parents

Answer (score 0):

go to info.plist open it as sourcecode   you will see like this

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```

remove

```
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```